# Recovering access to my unlinked Clash of Clans village

Tags: clash-of-clans

I seem to have lost access to my previous village since I recently switched to another phone. I didn't link it to an account I own but I do have all the local account / village information. Is there a way to recover my previous village? 
My account details (if relevant) are below:

Username is sanjubaba, town hall 8th, clan name India, and xp level is 49. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWUon.jpg)[image: Screenshot of Clash of Clans Information]

Answer (score 0):

On apple devices it is possible to retrieve it by signing into game center as your old account. After this go into clash of clans and a message should pop up saying `load village` press yes to proceed.

> WARNING: Current progress can NEVER be restored once you click the button yes!

Alternatively you can go to the clash of clans settings and click `link accounts`